# Can I handle Android fragmentation all by myself for my VOIP app?

Tags: android, voip

I built a very VOIP app for android phones.  All i have is a text field that lets a user enter the username of the person they'd like to call.  Then when they press call, it will wake up the recipients phone and play a ring tone.  The recipient can answer or decline the call.

At the moment the app "almost" works fine on the following devices:

- Galaxy Note 1 with OS 4.0.4
- GS3 with OS 4.2.2 and 4.3
- GS2 with OS 4.0.4
- Nexus 4 with OS 4.2.2

Some minor issues I'm having are calls between **some** GS2 phones (GT-S7530M) to **some** GS3 phones, where the audio is extremely quiet.  I'm not sure why this is, even though we maxed out the volume.  Other times, there's plenty of crackling in the calls, or you miss out on people's sentences.  We made sure the network speed was always at least 15mbps download and 1.5mbps upload.

Every other phone seems to work fine.

I am using linphone as the sip library for the phone.  I am using asterisk as the telephone server.  I am using GSM as the codec for the phone and for the asterisk server.  I'm pretty sure I'm not doing anything "special" with my code.  It's a simple app and I think any experienced Android developer will find my code pretty minimal and simple.

**My question is, assuming I correct the issues for the targeted phones above, is it realistic for a single programmer to attempt to make this voip app work on 70% of modern android phones that are running OS 4.x+?  Let's assume I want to be able to hit 70% target within a few weeks.**

Some of you might think my question is too broad, so I want to make it clear that i'm just looking for a yes or no answer to whether it's realistic or not and the reason for your answer.

The reason I'm asking is because I had an earlier prototype, and I asked some strangers with other phones like Sony Xperia ZL, HTC One etc... and they seemed to have problems getting my app to work correctly.  They experienced problems like the ring tone didn't work, or they couldn't receive a call (even though they successfully connected to my asterisk server), or the audio quality was extremely poor.  This led me to do a bit more research on the popular problem known as Android Fragmentation.  When I saw all the android phones out there, it scared me.   **Can I really reach 70% of modern android phones running OS 4.x all by myself in the next two weeks?**  Will this new version that I've created with bug fixes for Note 1, S3, S2 and Nexus 4 work perfectly on the other phones?

Comment: Surely there can't be that much mutations of problems that occur right? Maybe the problems only occur on a certain version of Android? It seems unlikely that you need to put out hundreds of unique bug fixes for each device.

Comment: In my earlier tests with my prototype that experienced a lot of issues,  I failed to check the network speed. Now I'm wondering if things like failed to receive calls, poor call quality, dropped connections etc...is related to it.  With tests on my newest version (I changed codecs and sip library), i'm making sure the bandwidth is reasonable.  So far, its ONLY my GS2 (GT-S7530M) that's having audio quality issues.  I am so worried that this problem will appear on other phones.  But its so difficult for me to find friends who have other phones to test this with me.

Comment: It's re-assuring to me when you say it seems unlikely that i need to put out hundres of unique bug fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's a very simple app

I long for the day when we can actually describe a custom VOIP app as being simple. It's 2013, and we cannot say that today with any degree of accuracy. IMHO, your app is rather complicated. It just so happens that most of the complicated bits are in a glob of open source code that you did not write (linphone) and a third-party server that you did not write (Asterisk).

> It's a simple app and I think any experienced Android developer would find my code pretty minimal and simple

Pretty much all of the symptoms that you have described would either be part of linphone or part of Asterisk, from what I can tell. Your *code* may be simple, but your *app* is not.

> is it realistic for a single programmer to attempt to make this voip app work on 70% of modern android phones that are running OS 4.x+?

If you remove linphone and Asterisk from the equation -- say, by rewriting your app to play a ringtone based upon an [GCM user notification](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html) -- your objective seems reasonable.

However, since your app as presently constituted is almost completely linphone and Asterisk ("any experienced Android developer would find my code pretty minimal and simple"), your success is gated by how well linphone works on Android, and how well linphone-on-Android works when communicating with Asterisk.
Hence, the only people who will be able to answer that are those experienced with those technologies. You might try asking on some dedicated linphone and/or Asterisk resources. Or, you might ask fresh StackOverflow questions, with tags appropriate for those technologies, with more focus.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Some carriers inflict inanity: sip hostility or not awesome flavors of IPv4 to IPv6.

Answer (score -1):

Currently I am also working on an Android VoIP client.
Actually there is no any difference between the different hardware and OS versions except this audio handling headache.

Unfortunately there are a lot of inconsistencies in the audio implementation by the different vendors. I would suggest you to have a look at some open source SIP softphone source code such as sipdroid, mizudroid and csipsimple. I was learnt a lot especially from sipdroid, although the code is not well commented. Be prepared to a lot of workaround handling each devices differently.